# When a "formatting" suggested edit is the reason the asker didn't understand

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Today I saw a suggested edit where the editor simply changed the whitespace and indentation of the posted code.

However, **the likely reason the question asker didn't understand what they were asking about was BECAUSE of this formatting problem**.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5083008

So:

- The edit was correct
- The edit did not change the meaning of the post (as it was just formatting)
- But it did change the understanding of what the problem was for future readers.

Is it a correct edit or not?

Comment: I don't see how the poor formatting was causing the problem. The asker obviously just didn't know about anonymous classes, a basic language feature. Answer it or close it as a duplicate. Next question.

Comment: I don't think so, in fact Iv'e had times where I would format over 100 lines of code all originally left indented and my edit is rejected. This edit was  not was necessary, in the comments that line of code was explained. Editing should only be done when necessary (for suggested edits), not to make a small part slightly nicer looking.

Comment: @CodyGray No I mean when I suggest edits and add formatting to long code segments they have been rejected before. Not that I have rejected them. I mean in this case it's a very small indentation edit.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek But they should not have been rejected. Doing proper code indentation is great! If you had your edit rejected then you should have complained because it was totally valid to make.

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer I'm not sure we can go as far as saying they're "totally valid." Questions with poorly formatted code generally include a number of other issues that *should* be fixed at the same time. That said, I'm usually more lenient with approving those suggested edits because I hate reading poorly formatted code far more than I hate reading mangled English.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist You are correct. Still, having fixed 100+ lines of indentation is a great improvement to a post, even if something else got overlooked in the process. Given that nothing got broke through the edit I'd always approve it.

Answer (score 39):

If the formatting was truly *essential* to understanding or reproducing the problem, then the edit changed the meaning of the post.

If that's true, then roll it back.

Comment: I thought clarification was a perfectly valid reason to edit a post. If changing the meaning of the post actually clarifies it (whether it be by formatting, or grammar, or whatever), then why roll it back?

Comment: @ouflak Changing the meaning of a post isn't clarification — basically, if you've changed the meaning, you've gone too far.

Comment: Indeed. When such an edit should actually have been an answer, or a comment. There is even a special reject reason for that.

Comment: I guess it might come down to semantics. If the original post was so muddled as to be unable to determine what the author was asking, and you change the formatting to clarify it correctly, you've changed the meaning (which was basic meaningless previously) and you've made a good edit.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a correct edit.

It forces the editor's idea of preferred style on everyone else, when the existing style is not clearly problematic.  Rather like the difference between 3 space indent and 4 space indent, or opening braces following the method signature vs on a new line.

There's nothing stylistically wrong with a very short method body being on a single line.  It isn't even causing scrolling.

For example, in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24300563/103167) I really hate the following patterns:

```
struct Name {
```

and

```
} else
```

Both of those *ought* to have a newline, in my preferred style.  But I'm not going to submit an edit doing so.

Comment: Your preferred style wastes space and allows you to see less code at a time.

Comment: @DanielDarabos That depends on the orientation of your monitor

Comment: I guess I should try more orientations :). Mostly it's a matter of what you are used to, I think. So, apologies for being a smartass.

Comment: @DanielDarabos: Ah, but what is the advantage of seeing more code at a time?  The true goal is finding code faster, and understanding it more easily.  Reducing scrolling is beneficial to both, but so is appropriate use of whitespace.  Where is the tradeoff?

Comment: If someone needs to see more code on reasonably sized screen resolutions, then either the method to large, the editor doesn't support enough options for finding code (e.g. Find All References), or the programmer isn't using the tools effectively.  If wasting space is truly a problem, then I would imagine a smaller font would be more effective means of displaying more code.